# Colocar separador de miles C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

como puedo lograr que se me visualice el separador de miles, le hago mantenimiento a una aplicación que trabaja con el patron MVC en ASP.NET, la aplicación busca un producto en tiempo real el cual viene con el siguiente formato: **TANG NARANJA SP SOBRE 30G Precio: 475020.00** coloca con puntos los decimales y  al momento de guardarlo para mostrarlo se ve de la siguiente manera

**COMO SE GUARDA = 475020,00**

**OBJETIVO = 475.020,00**

Hay alguna manera de lograrlo?

En el Modelo tiene una clase que se llama Item

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            precio = 0;
    
        }

        public decimal precio;
    }
```

En el Controlador tiene una clase que se llama Ordenes

```
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(collection["listaProductos"].Trim());
                foreach (Item i in items)
                {
                    int indexPrecio = i.nombre.IndexOf(" Precio: ");
                    if (indexPrecio != -1)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                        i.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] { "Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        i.nombre = i.nombre.Substring(0, indexPrecio);                        
                    }
                }
```

En esta linea establecí CurrentCulture y CurrentUICulture, ya que con ellas puedo agregar el formato para el separador de miles pero aun así no funciona, no se si me esta faltando algo en agregar

```
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    i.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] { "Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

ANEXO UNA IMAGEN DE COMO SE VE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AQUI ANEXO EL CODIGO DE LA VISTA

```
@using TPConvenios.App_Data;
@model Orden
@{
    Layout = null;
        
    List<TPConvenios.Models.AtributoAdicional> atributosAdicionales = ViewBag.AtributosAdicionales;
}
<style>
    .box { width: 500px; float: left; height:25px}
</style>
<div style="margin: 10px 20px 0">
    <input type="hidden" id="idOrden" name="idOrden" value="@Model.idOrden" />
    <span class="filterRight" id="selectorEstatusProducto" style="display: none">Productos:
        <select id="selProductos" style="max-width: 250px">
            <option value="-1">Todos</option>
            <option value="1" selected>No Eliminados</option>
            <option value="0">Eliminados</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <h1>
        Orden N° @Model.idOrden <span style="color: red">@(Model.FechaHasta.Date < DateTime.Now.Date ? "Vencida" : (!Model.Activa ? "Inactiva" : string.Empty))
            @(Model.Eliminada ? " - Eliminada" : string.Empty)</span></h1>
    <input type="button" class="botonNuevo" value="Versión PDF" onclick="VerOrdenPdf(@Model.idOrden)" style="height: 28px;
            width: 110px; font-size: 13px; float: right;" />
    @if (ViewBag.esEditable)
    {
        <input type="button" class="botonNuevo" value="Editar" onclick="NuevaOrden(@Model.idOrden)" style="height: 28px;
            width: 110px; font-size: 13px; float: right;" />
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Paciente</strong>
            </td>
            <td>@String.Format("CI/RIF {2}. {1} - {0}", Model.NombreBeneficiario, Model.CiRifBeneficiario, ((TPConvenios.Models.General.eNacionalidad)Model.Nacionalidad).ToString())
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Vigencia</strong>
            </td>
            <td>@String.Format("Desde {0:dd-MM-yyyy} hasta {1:dd-MM-yyyy}", Model.FechaDesde, Model.FechaHasta)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
    @if (atributosAdicionales != null)
        {
            int cont = 0;
            <div class="box"> 
            @foreach (TPConvenios.Models.AtributoAdicional atr in atributosAdicionales)
            {                                   
                <strong>@atr.Descripcion </strong> @atr.Valor                
            }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="div_tblPosiciones">
        <table id="tblPosiciones">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Producto
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        Cantidad Orden
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        Entregado Total
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">Cantidad por</span> Entregar
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        Precio UN.
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        Total
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/" + String.Format("Scripts/jsOrden/jsNuevaOrden.js?v={0}", File.GetLastWriteTime(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Scripts/jsOrden/jsNuevaOrden.js").ToString("yyyyMMddHHss")))' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Agradeciera muchos si me ayudaran o me guiaran para solventar este error

Comment: El código no parece incorrecto. Sólo que deberías mostrar el código en el punto en que quieres mostrar el precio en el PDF. Allí deberías hacer algo así como `i.precio.ToString("N2");`

Comment: Amigo edite la pregunta ya que no es tan solo en el PDF,

Comment: esto varia en funcion del equipo y la localizacion regional; en algunos casos america latina por ejemplo los decimales se separan por punto. y la coma separa miles y para guardar en base de dato tienen un tipo dependiendo del tamaño del numero y no lleva separadores de miles...

Comment: Pero pones el código de cómo obtienes el valor numérico, pero no de cómo lo renderizas. Si el problema es el formato al mostrar el dato haría falta ver el código de la vista.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Alli anexe el código de la vista, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez exacto estoy consiente de eso aun quitandole la localización regional se almacena de la misma forma

Comment: @TheRiddler en el código de la vista no muestras el listado de artículos. Entiendo que eso lo haces dinámicamente con código js. El código que habría que revisar es el que muestra el artículo con su precio.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva hablas de la parte que aun no se guarda el precio? la imagen que anexe es una ves guardado el producto con su precio!

Answer (score 3):

Debes tener claro que si pones un número nunca va a tener separador de miles porque las variables numéricas no las tienen en ningún lenguaje, cuando quieres dar un formato a un número lo que haces es obtener un **string** del número con el formato deseado, entonces en donde sea que muestres la variable *precio* debes reemplazarlo por un string formateado, algo así:

```
double dd = 1234.123;
string usFormated = dd.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
string clFormated = dd.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("es-CL")); // sip soy chileno
```

y ya en el pdf o donde sea, muestras la variable usFormated, que puedes agregarla al objeto Item y darle formato en el constructor por ejemplo

código de ejemplo
https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2sMuS

Comment: No funciona amigo @LPZadkiel

Comment: agregué un enlace donde está el código funcionando, en tu caso puede que tengas un overlapping de formateo. Quizás estas mostrando los datos en un navegador web que no tiene el idioma que deseas, o al generar el pdf lo estas haciendo con un formato por defecto y te sobre escribe el texto, eso ya es un poco mas difícil de ver

Comment: No puedo agregar el enlace debido a que es algo local en mi maquina de desarrollo, el idioma de mi navegador es Español-España y mi CurrentCulture es "es-VE", accediendo al enlace si funciona perfectamente pero al quererlo aplicar en mi proyecto no hace ningún efecto

Comment: Hola, estaba buscando esto mismo y me funcionó con ToString("N", new CultureInfo("es-CL"). Pero me gustaría saber como sacarle los decimales. Muchas Gracias

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda te puedo dejar un link donde preguntan eso, en este link usan dos formas: `Math.round()` y y `numero.toFixed()`, ahí verás tu cual te conviene/gusta más usar (tener en cuenta que toFixed te convierte tu número en texto). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary

Comment: @SebastianMiranda, para mmostrar los decimales solo debes colocar despues de la N un cero asi: ToString("N00");