# Como Colocar Separador De Miles A Un Tipo De Dato Decimal C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas para ver como coloco los separadores de miles a un tipo de dato **Decimal**, he intentado varias forma para darle el formato que necesito y no logro hacerlo, quiero intentarlo sin cambiar el tipo de Dato es decir siempre debe mantenerse el Tipo de Dato **Decimal**.

Al ejecutar obtengo siempre este valor **1450,00**
El Resultado que quiero Conseguir **1.450,00**

Tengo en Mi Clase **Program.cs** el siguiente Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace N_D
{
    
        class Program : Test
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                var price = 1450.00;

                Test P = new Test();

                P.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(price.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("es-VE")));

                Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + P.precio);

                Console.Read();

            }
        }    
}
```

tengo otra clase llamada **Test.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace N_D
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            precio = 0;

        }

        public decimal precio;
    }
}
```

Agradeceria si me ayudaran, formule esta misma pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413288/colocar-separador-de-miles-c), pero cambie de escenario de manera que puedan ayudarme copiando estas lineas de códigos y ejecutarlas en sus VisualStudio

Comment: _quiero intentarlo sin cambiar el tipo de Dato es decir siempre debe mantenerse el Tipo de Dato Decimal._ Creo que tienes un error de concepto. Un dato `decimal` no tiene formato. El formato se le pone cuando se convierte a string para mostrarlo en el `Console.WriteLine`. En ese momento, puedes formatearlo para que aparezca como te interese (prueba por ejemplo `.ToString("N")` o `.ToString("#,##0.00")`

Comment: @Pikoh me mal interpretas, quise decir en pocas palabras que su  tipo de dato inicial sera decimal, y luego convertirlo a string para darle el formato que deseo.  ya hice esa prueba y no funciono sigue mostrando 1450,00

Comment: Perdona si no te entendí bien, pero te di la solución en mi comentario creo:  `Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + P.precio.ToString("N"));` o `Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + P.precio.ToString("#,##0.00")`

Comment: Aunque analizando tu codigo creo que no andaba yo muy desencaminado. Cuando haces el `Convert.ToDecimal` estas intentado que se meta con los separadores de miles (`price.ToString("N",`) ... pero eso nunca te va a funcionar. `Decimal` no tiene formato, solo una parte entera y una decimal

Comment: Había entendido mal yo, colócalo como respuesta para colocarla como útil

Comment: @Pikoh quiero preguntart algo en la linea donde coloco Convert.ToDecimal no hay manera de que quede con el formato deseado, debe ser siempre en la salida de la variable? es lo que intentas decir cuando dices que nunca funcionara?

Comment: No, como explico en mi respuesta un `decimal` no tiene "formato" . Es una estructura con dos `int`, una para la parte entera, y otra para la decimal. Y un `int` no tiene formato, es una representacion numérica

Comment: Perfecto, Gracias amigo @Pikoh

Answer (score 4):

`decimal` no tiene formato. Es una estructura con dos partes, una entera y una decimal.

El formato se da cuando se convierte a `string` para mostrarse. Es en ese momento cuando se puede definir dicho formato, usando por ejemplo `ToString`:

```
Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + P.precio.ToString("N"));
```

o

```
Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + P.precio.ToString("#,##0.00")
```

Por completar, esto es innecesario:

```
P.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(price.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("es-VE")));
```

puedes simplemente hacer:

```
P.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(price);
```

o mejor aun:

```
decimal price = 1450.00;
```