# Separador de miles C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mvc

Estoy retomando un proyecto y le hago mantenimiento, quiero agregar el separador de miles a un produtco que muestra su precio unitario y total. Este trabaja con MVC esta misma pregunta la formule [Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413288/colocar-separador-de-miles-c) solo que ya se donde muestra el valor del Precio, para dar el formato que deseo.

**COMO SE GUARDA = 1000000,00**

**OBJETIVO = 1.000.000,00**

En el Modelo tiene una clase que se llama Item

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            precio = 0;
    
        }

        public decimal precio;
    }
```

En el Controlador tiene una clase que se llama Ordenes, aqui el obtiene el valor del precio

```
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(collection["listaProductos"].Trim());
            foreach (Item i in items)
            {
                
                int indexPrecio = i.nombre.IndexOf(" Precio: ");
                if (indexPrecio != -1)
                {
                    
                    i.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] { "Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                  
                    i.nombre = i.nombre.Substring(0, indexPrecio);
                   
                }
            }
```

En esa misma clase que se llama Ordenes tiene este codigo que es donde lo imprime, donde dice PRECIO no se como colocarle el formato pues he intentado con lo siguiente:

1. `posicion.PRECIO.ToString("N")` o `posicion.PRECIO.ToString("N2")` y me marca rojo
2. `posicion.PRECIO = Convert.ToString("N2"),` tambien me marca en rojo

   [Authorize]

   ```
        private List<string[]> ProductosToView(IEnumerable<PosicionOrden> listadoProductos)
        {
            List<string[]> result = new List<string[]>();
            HtmlHelper helper = GetHtmlHelper(this);
            foreach (var posicion in listadoProductos)
            {
                result.Add(new string[] {
                    posicion.nombreMedicamento,
                    posicion.cantidadMaxima.ToString(),
                    RenderPartialViewToString(this, "DetalleEntregasProducto", posicion),                    
                    (posicion.cantidadMaxima-posicion.cantidadEntregada).ToString(),

                    posicion.PRECIO.ToString(),


                    (posicion.PRECIO * posicion.cantidadMaxima).ToString(),

                    (posicion.eliminado? " OrdenEliminada":string.Empty),
                    posicion.idPosicionOrden.ToString(),
                    posicion.codigoMedicamento,
                    posicion.cantidadEntregada.ToString()                    
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
   ```

Si pudieran ayudarme de como colocar en esa linea la manera para imprimirlo se lo agradeceria

Comment: precio es decimal... vos tenes que transformar el string que mostras...

Comment: tranformarlo dentro del mismo foreach?

Comment: posicion.PRECIO.ToString(), aca es donde tenes que transformarlo...

Comment: Intente con esto: posicion.PRECIO = Convert.ToString("N2") y me arroja error lo marca en rojo, tal como lo formule en la pregunta

Comment: no. precio es un decimal, no un string... no tiene formato.. y Convert.ToString no es nada, ya que le estas pasando un string.. mira el error... tu transformacion tiene que hacerse en la pantalla, no en la variable... la transformacion es en el result, cuando justamente estas haciendo posicion.PRECIO.ToString(),

Comment: En la pregunta que hiciste originalmente, ademas que no aceptaste la respuesta, que es correcta, te estan explicando exactamente lo mismo que preguntas aca. Me parece que no entendiste la diferencia entre decimal y string.. y que lo que muestra la pantalla puede ser con cualquier formato porque no es lo que guarda la variable decimal, a la cual no le importa el formato

Comment: dices que te lo marca en rojo, has puesto el cursor encima a ver que mensaje te sale? Veo que tienes 4 preguntas con el mismo problema, tienes la solución en respuestas anteriores, usa la cabeza y piensa!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta por duplicada y dejar el debate antes que las cosas se calienten más.

Comment: @gbianchi si vote como útil, y creo que no he entendido muy bien, quizás ustedes lo ven porque tienen mas experiencia en esto y  yo no

Comment: @NicolasOñate da errores como que no existe en el documento actual o no se puede convertir un decimal a string, estoy pensando en como lograrlo solo que aun no lo veo a diferencia de ustedes.

Comment: @Excorpion Lo que ustedes crean mejor son los expertos ustedes

Comment: No. si no soluciono tu problema, entonces hace un seguimiento hasta que se solucione. volver a preguntar lo mismo, sin haber entendido que tu problema es otra, no sirve para nada... La solucion a tu problema es que entiendas lo que te dicen las respuestas que te dieron. En la variable decimal, se guarda un numero decimal, SIN FORMATO. y la variable, se queda sin formato. cuando la mostras en pantalla, es cuando le das formato... Esta pregunta, es lo mismo que ya preguntaste 2 veces anteriores.. el problema es el mismo...

Comment: y si tenes mas dudas, te podemos ayudar en el [chat]

Comment: @Excorpion aqui lo entendi perfectamente, pero el proyecto me cuesta verlo

Comment: por eso lo separe para entender mejor

Comment: Ignora eso, es un reporte de duplicada lo que hice, el comentario es automatico, no lo hice yo

Comment: @gbianchi agradezco mucho tu ayuda en verdad pero sigo sin verlo, respondem algo arriba me dijiste que la transformacion debo hacerlo en el result, cuando sale del foreach debo transformarlo ?

Comment: no. dentro del for! eso es lo que mostras en pantalla, y eso es lo que tenes que transformar, lo que esta en la pantalla.... Y es lo que te explicaron en todas las respuestas que te dieron....

Comment: intentare transformarlo dentro de ese for entonces. Gracias @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi coloque lo siguiente posicion.PRECIO.Value.ToString("N"), agregue el value, y ahora tengo el separador de miles al hacerlo me lo transforma?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como Colocar Separador De Miles A Un Tipo De Dato Decimal C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423565/como-colocar-separador-de-miles-a-un-tipo-de-dato-decimal-c)

Comment: @Javifer2 Gracias por comentar, pero ya coloque la Respuesta y en los comentarios de abajo donde tenia el problema

Answer (score 0):

Agregue Value a `posicion.PRECIO.ToString(),`

Quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
posicion.PRECIO.Value.ToString("N"),
```

Lo mismo para

```
(posicion.PRECIO * posicion.cantidadMaxima).Value.ToString("N"),
```

Lo Coloque así y funciono

Comment: Y entendiste porque esa es la solucion? que es lo mismo que te dijeron en todas las otras publicaciones?

Comment: @gbianchi, si estaba confundido, al agregar Value, le asigno a esa propiedad el parámetro que deseo en este caso a esa cadena le asigno el especificador de formato numérico ("N") pero ya me quedo claro. siempre tuve la respuesta desde el inicio y no lograba verla. Muchas Gracias