# Miles separator in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hay alguna forma en C# de que una cantidad tenga un separador de miles por ejemplo con comas " , " ??

**var number = 123456**

lo que quiero

**number = 123,456**

Comment: Maria, este es un foro en español no ingles. Edita tu pregunta si quieres recibir respuesta.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: si.. al mostrarlo podes mostrarlo como quieras... cual fue el problema que tuviste???

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, mi duda era que cuando diera cantidades grandes se separaran por comas para que asi sea mas facil visualizar por ejemplo 10,000 ó 15,00,150 etc etc (Encontre una solución para ello)

Comment: lo que hice fue agregar este tipo de formato *Total.ToString("#,###")*  en otra variable ya que es una conversión.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu pregunta es respecto de cómo puedes añadir separadores en el código para mejorar la legibilidad, C# permite que insertes el caracter '_' en cualquier posición de un número, tanto entero como decimal; el compilador lo eliminará del código resultante:

```
int x = 123_456_789;
```

Si lo que quieres es añadir separadores en el momento de la visualización, normalmente por consola, el método **ToString** tiene varias sobrecargas que permiten indicar el tipo de salida deseada (**FormatProvider**) y el contexto cultural (**CultureInfo**); ya fue respondida por otro usuario:

[Colocar separador de miles C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413288/colocar-separador-de-miles-c)

Cuando tengas dudas, echa siempre un vistazo a la documentación oficial de la [API](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/?view=net-6.0)

Un saludo

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]... de paso, si la pregunta es duplicada, se cierra por duplicada... nunca habia visto de agregar _ en un entero, podrias indicarme donde esta eso en la documentacion?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/digit-separators

Comment: interesante.. se ve que me lo habia perdido, porque no tiene mucho uso, salvo para constantes.. no seria el caso para cualquier otro numero....